# How to add custom html in product listing page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-list

I want to add my custom html at product listing page.

Screenshot:

[image]

How I do this?

Comment: have you got solution ?

Comment: Please explain which html you need.

Comment: @pavan. I want any html like `<div>My Content Here</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change **list.phtml** in theme level or overwrite into your custom module.

File location is:

**Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml**

Add your div/custom text after following line of code:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
```

After your change don't forget to clear cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have custom module and i dont want to override list.phtml file in mymodule.

Answer (score 0):

My Magento version is 2.3.x (I think the later version will have this logic). We can use Layout Logic. I think it's the best practice.

From the Magento default, we have the block name `category.product.type.details.renderers.default` (vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml), but it doesn't have a template to show the "real" content. This block will be called in template

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

```
<?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>
```

But, no template and we will have no content. So, my solution is to add the template for this block.

app/code/Vendor/Model/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\Listing\Brand" name="product.brand" template="Vendor_Module::product/list/brand.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

We also add a child block to build our custom logic.

Getting child html:

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

```
<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildHtml('', false); ?>
```

Child block logic

Vendor\Module\Block\Product\Listing\Brand

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\Listing;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Brand extends Template
{

    /**
     * @return Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getProduct();
    }
}
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list/brand.phtml

```
// <?= $block->getProduct()->getBrand() ?>;
<?= __("Your custom text"); ?>
```

[image]